# SQL merging lines into one line

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question about an SQL query.

I have a table with these column names:
`date` `time` `route_id` `name`

(and other columns not included here):

| Date | route_id | Time | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-04 | 320 | 11:40:00 | Taxi |
| 2022-02-04 | 320 | 14:35:00 | Taxi |

I have made the following query:

```
Select
date,
LEFT(route_id_intern,4) as route_id,
CASE 
       WHEN time < '12:00:00' THEN 'Morning' 
       ELSE 'Free' END as 'Morning',
CASE 
       WHEN time > '12:00:00' THEN 'Afternoon' 
       ELSE 'Free' END as 'Afternoon',
Name,
FROM [DW2].[dbo].[FCT_RITTEN]
where year(date) = 2022 and month(date)=02 and day(date) = 04 
and LEFT(route_id_intern,4) = 3209
```

My query gives the following result:

| Date | route_id | Moring | Afternoon | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-04 | 320 | Morning | Free | Taxi |
| 2022-02-04 | 320 | Free | Afternoon | Taxi |

The data stays separated in two lines but I would like to have following result:

| Date | route_id | Moring | Afternoon | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-04 | 320 | Morning | Afternoon | Taxi |

I have tried several methods but I keep getting these separated lines.

Please note the used data is anonymized for the data in the above samples but the problem stays the same.

Update:

After the reply of @HoneyBadger, I have amended my query:

```
Select
date,
LEFT(route_id_intern,3) as route_id,
MAX(CASE 
       WHEN time <= '12:00:00' THEN '1' 
       ELSE '0' END) as 'Morning',
MAX(CASE 
       WHEN time > '12:00:00' THEN '1' 
       ELSE '0' END) as 'Afternoon'
FROM [DW2].[dbo].[FCT_RITTEN]
where date = '2022-02-04'
and LEFT(route_id_intern,4) = 320
group by date, route_id_intern
```

Unfortunately, the result is still not as needed:

| Date | route_id | Morning | Afternoon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-04 | 320 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-02-04 | 320 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: What database do you use ?

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server

Comment: To have a column `Morning`, which is either filled with `'Morning'` or `'Free'` is a bit odd. How about renaming it to `MorningShift`, and filling it with `1` or `0` (true/false)? Then you can simply take the `MAX()`. And likewise for `Afternoon`

Comment: In your question you share a query and a table. In your query there are columns: plan_datum and route_id_intern. This columns are not in the table you shared ?

Comment: I would suggest in your where clause to use "where plan_datum = '20220204'" instead of all those functions. And then you can also use "route_id_inter like '3209%'". Functions in the where predicates are non-sargable and in this case are not needed.

Comment: @VBoka I have amended plan_datum to date in order to make the query correct and route_id_intern is turned into route _id at line 3.

Comment: @HoneyBadger, thank you for your reply! I have amended me query but I keep getting the same result. I have updated my question.

Comment: @SeanLange the date filter was just the create a usage sample. The original table contains thousands of rows. I have ameded the filter in my question.  The LEFT(route_id_intern,4)  is use the translate our internal route numbers to the route numbers from our subcontractors.

Comment: @Catscanner given that you have thousands of rows you really need to not use functions.  Using like with a trailing wildcard will outperform a left any day of the week. And all those functions on your date just as bad. Both of those prevent any indexes from being utilized.

Comment: Also please not that the only 100% accurate string representation of a date is yyyymmdd. No dashes or anything else. Any other string format can sometimes be misinterpreted based on the language setting.

Comment: @Catscanner please double check the updated query, it doesn't match the stated result now. Probably a bit too quick to copy-paste

Comment: @HoneyBadger thank for noticing. I have updated my query to the one matching the outcome.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for your comments. I have removed the filter functions in my updates query.  Regarding the date I have update my query. I does not solve this problem, but it will possibly prevent future problems.

Comment: @Catscanner yes indeed. My point was to help with this and any other future queries so your sql will be fast.

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you! I am sure your comments will help me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there I guess. Removing the group by and putting your query inside a cte and then playing with the time column a bit as below will give you the desired result.

```
;with cte as(
Select
date,
LEFT(route_id_intern,4) as route_id,
CASE 
   WHEN max(time)over(partition by date,name order by date) > '12:00:00' 
   and count(1)over(partition by date,name order by date) > 1 
   THEN 'Morning-Afternoon'
   WHEN max(time)over(partition by date,name order by date) = '12:00:00' 
   and count(1)over(partition by date,name order by date) > 1 
   THEN 'Morning-Lunch'
   when max(time)over(partition by date,name order by date) > '12:00:00' 
   and count(1)over(partition by date,name order by date) = 1
   then 'Free-Afternoon'
   when max(time)over(partition by date,name order by date) < '12:00:00' 
   and count(1)over(partition by date,name order by date) = 1
   then 'Morning-Free'
   END as 'day',
Name,
FROM [DW2].[dbo].[FCT_RITTEN]
where year(date) = 2022 and month(date)=02 and day(date) = 04 
and LEFT(route_id_intern,4) = 3209
)
select distinct Date,route_id
,SUBSTRING([day],1,charindex('-',[day])-1) as [Morning]
,SUBSTRING([day],charindex('-',[day])+1,len([day])) as [Afternoon]
,name
 from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

One the challenges here is that your sample data and query don't line up. There are columns referenced in your query not in your sample data. I think this is likely because you obfuscated the real information so much that some details got lost. I made some best guesses and I think that what you need is conditional aggregation. At the very least this will return the desired output you wanted based (mostly) on the sample provided.

```
create table FCT_RITTEN
(
    MyDate date
    , route_id int
    , MyTime time
    , Name varchar(10)
)

insert FCT_RITTEN
select '20220204', 320, '11:40:00', 'Taxi' union all
select '20220204', 320, '14:35:00', 'Taxi'

Select
    MyDate
    , route_id
    , Morning = max(CASE WHEN MyTime < '12:00:00' THEN 'Morning' END)
    , Afternoon = max(CASE WHEN MyTime > '12:00:00' THEN 'Afternoon' END)
    , Name
FROM [dbo].[FCT_RITTEN]
where MyDate = '20220204'
    and route_id like '320%' --Why are you doing a string comparison on an integer column?
group by MyDate
    , route_id
    , Name
```